# Share the same SQLite database in Android activities

Tags: android, database, sqlite

How do I share the same SQLite database among multiple Acitivties?

Basically, here is my database structure:

Each time I need to query or update my database in other activities, I'll have to make a new object. For example, `Database db = new Database(classname.this);`

Since each activity is going to make a database object for itself, there's no way I can make these activies to share the same data in the same database...

```
public class Database {
    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_NAME = "food_name";
    public static final String KEY_HOTNESS = "food_hotness";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "myDB";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "foodTable";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private DbHelper ourHelper;
    private final Context ourContext;
    private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;

    private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
        public DbHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
                       KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                       KEY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                       KEY_HOTNESS + " TEXT NOT NULL);"
                      );
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + DATABASE_TABLE);
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }

    public Database(Context c) {
        ourContext = c; //Different objects...how to solve?
    }

    public Database open() throws SQLException {
        ourHelper = new DbHelper(ourContext);
        ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close() {
        ourHelper.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Please read this:

http://www.touchlab.co/blog/single-sqlite-connection/

You should share the same SQLiteOpenHelper between your activities.  If you're careful you don't need to, but you can get into trouble if you do things the wrong way.

Basically, keep a SQLiteOpenHelper as a singleton and use that from everywhere.

Comment: Broken link, new one: http://touchlabblog.tumblr.com/post/24474750219/single-sqlite-connection

Answer (score -1):

You don't have to do anything else except use your database helper. It will make sure all your activities access the same database. Even though you'll have different database helper objects in each Activity, they'll all be accessing the same database.

Answer (score -1):

Check the documentation on the getWriteableDatabase() function.  You'll see that it's not opening a new database object each time.  It keeps it in cache until you close it.  the onCreate() only the first time when necessary or on an upgrade of version.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#getWritableDatabase()